# Is there a Linux system call that lets me make system calls in the context of another process?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

What I want to do is make a system call, and have the kernel act as if it was a different process making the call. You could think of it like impersonating another process. I know I could mess with the program's code using ptrace, but that's not very elegant and probably requires tweaking to work with whatever process I'm doing. Plus what I'm asking should be possible for the kernel without having to touch the other process's memory or execution process, unless of course the effect of the system call I'm performing would cause that.

The way I'm thinking it would work would be to have a (privileged) system call (let's call it `setepid`, for "set effective PID") that accepts a PID as an argument. After `setepid`, any future system calls made by that process (or maybe only that thread) will behave as if it was the specified process making the system call. The exception is the `setepid` call itself, which can be used to restore the original context or otherwise target a different process.

For example, the following code could be used to redirect the standard output of an already-running process (PID 1234 in this example) to the file `output.txt`, located in process 1234's current working directory:

```
setepid(1234); /* perform following system calls on process 1234 */

int fd = open("output.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC);
if (fd > 0) {
    dup2(fd, 1);
    close(fd);
}

setepid(0); /* done acting as 1234, restore original context */
```

One possible issue this might have is the `"output.txt"` string constant, which is passed as a pointer. Depending on how `setepid` is implemented, perhaps out of necessity, it might be treating that pointer as an address in process 1234's memory. As it doesn't even make sense to statically allocate memory (including for a constant) in another process at compile-time, getting around that would require something ugly like this instead:

```
setepid(1234);
char *buf = mmap(NULL, 12, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
setepid(0);

const char *str = "output.txt\0"; /* extra byte to make it a multiple of 4 */
/* Disclaimer: I'm not sure if I'm using ptrace correctly, but you get the idea. */
ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, 1234, NULL, NULL);
ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, 1234, buf, *(void**)str);
ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, 1234, buf+4, *(void**)(str+4));
ptrace(PTRACE_POKEDATA, 1234, buf+8, *(void**)(str+8));
ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, 1234, NULL, NULL);

setepid(1234);

int fd = open(buf, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC);
if (fd > 0) {
    dup2(fd, 1);
    close(fd);
}

setepid(0);
```

I'm assuming such a mechanism doesn't exist, though I hope I'm wrong. If my assumption is correct, are there any issues that would prevent this from being added in a future version of Linux? Would it be simple (or even possible) to implement this in a kernel module? It sounds like it would be a dangerous, but powerful and potentially useful tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are proposing cannot work without effectively injecting code to the target thread and that much you can already do with ptrace.

One of the problems is that there is data which is only modified by the current thread. Since nobody else modifies it, it can be trivially read without locks. But with your approach, the invariant would break. A trivial example is credentials.

This does not work for the toy fd replacement case provided either. When doing any syscall taking fd as an argument, the target file pointer has to be found. If the fd table is shared, the file has to be referenced as someone else could close(fd) in the meantime. The kernel has a microoptimization for singlethreaded processes - since the table is not shared, there is nobody to close the fd, so there is no need to reference (and unref) it later. And once more, sudden modification of the fd table would easily lead to a use-after-free as you close the fd used by the thread.

And so on.

In short, there is no way this is going to fly. The closest thing you can do is inject syscalls with ptrace.

Comment: Makes sense. I was hoping to experiment with this, but thanks.